# Vue-google-map autocomplete two way binding not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2, google-maps-markers

I am using [vue-google-maps](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/), and I have implemented the plugin and it works flawlessly, but there is a small problem ( or maybe I am not able to do it correctly ). When I implemented the autocomplete functionality it works one way. I enter the address and the map points me to the selected place but when I drag the pointer it doesn't update the address in the search field. 
**I am using Vuejs 2** 
and [vue-google-maps](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/)

This is what I am doing:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <label>
            AutoComplete
            <GmapAutocomplete :position.sync="markers[0].position" @keyup.enter="usePlace" @place_changed="setPlace">
            </GmapAutocomplete>
            <button @click="usePlace">Add</button>
        </label>
        <br/>

        <gmap-map
            :center="center"
            :zoom="7"
            map-type-id="terrain"
            style="width: 100%; height: 500px"
        >
            <gmap-marker
                @dragend="updateMaker" 
                :key="index"
                v-for="(m, index) in markers"
                :position="m.position"
                :clickable="true"
                :draggable="true"
                @click="center=m.position"
            ></gmap-marker>

        </gmap-map>

    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                center: {lat: 10.0, lng: 10.0},
                markers: [{
                    position: {lat: 11.0, lng: 11.0}
                }],
                place: null,
            }
        },
        description: 'Autocomplete Example (#164)',
        methods: {
            setPlace(place) {
                this.place = place
            },
            setDescription(description) {
                this.description = description;
            },
            usePlace(place) {
                if (this.place) {
                    var newPostion = {
                        lat: this.place.geometry.location.lat(),
                        lng: this.place.geometry.location.lng(),
                    };
                    this.center = newPostion;
                    this.markers[0].position =  newPostion;
                    this.place = null;
                }
            },
            updateMaker: function(event) {
                console.log('updateMaker, ', event.latLng.lat());
                this.markers[0].position = {
                    lat: event.latLng.lat(),
                    lng: event.latLng.lng(),
                }
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is supported. You might have to implement this by yourself.

In your `updateMaker()` method, you could use `google.maps.Geocoder()` to find the address name yourself:

```
updateMaker: function(event) {
   const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
   geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': event.latLng }, (result, status) => {
       if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         // set the input field value with address:
         console.log(result[0].formatted_address)
       }
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add 'ref' to your auto complete component like :

```
<GmapAutocomplete ref="gmapAutocomplete" :position.sync="markers[0].position" @keyup.enter="usePlace" @place_changed="setPlace">
        </GmapAutocomplete>
```

Change updateMarker function to this:

```
updateMaker: function(event) {
    console.log('updateMaker, ', event.latLng.lat());
    this.markers[0].position = {
       lat: event.latLng.lat(),
       lng: event.latLng.lng(),
    }
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': event.latLng }, (result, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          this.$refs.gmapAutocomplete.$refs.input.value = result[0].formatted_address
        }
    })
},
```